# Passing an attribute's value of the clicked element to an external function through jquery .on() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

As a new comer to JS and jquery, I just can't seems to get this thing working! The alert gives `undefined`!

```
this.$el.on('click', '.chorse-item',{id:$(this).attr('id')}, this.handleItem);
this.handleItem = function(event) {
        alert(event.data.id);
}
```

It shows the "id" perfectly with

```
this.$el.on('click', '.chorse-item', function(){alert($(this).attr('id'))});
```

I suspect the `$(this).attr('id')` is falling out of scope or something? cause

```
this.$el.on('click', '.chorse-item',{id:"Testing"}, this.handleItem);
```

Shows the "Testing".

Comment: Show your full code? I don't understand what is `this` ?

Comment: Can you store id in a variable above the first line. var id = $(this).attr('id'). Then your third argument would be {id: id}

Comment: So, what is the problem if using the second approach?

Comment: The first method serves my purpose as I want to do more with the 'id' and I don't want to make the on() much cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to pass any data inside `.on` method, as it already available inside the calling function :

```
this.$el.on('click', '.chorse-item', this.handleItem );
this.handleItem = function(event) {
    // `this` here !=  with the this `this.handleItem`
    // this here would refer to this `.chorse-item` already
    // so just calling it using `this.id` or `$( this ).attr( 'id' )`
    // in order to get clicked element's id or anything else related
    alert(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this) in your non-working version is in the context of the function registering the onclick handler.  'id' is undefined because it's not an attribute of the object you are in at the time, and you are assigning that undefined attribute to the id property of the data object.

$(this) in the second working version is in the context of the element calling the declared function.

Who's 'id' attr are you wanting to get access to?  If it's the object that's clicked (which I suspect) then your second method is the way you want to be implementing this, and the first method is wrong for your purpose.

Comment: Norlihazmey Ghazali's answer solved my problem. The first method serves my purpose as I want to do more with the 'id' and I don't want to make the on() much cumbersome.